# Does cudaMallocHost() give access to pointers in struct

Tags: cuda

I am working on a project and I have a struct containing pointers. When I use cudaMalloc() and copy the struct to device memory, it seems that it does not copy the content pointed by the pointers in the host memory, which is obvious I guess. I went through few posts here where people have suggested to copy the entire content of struct.

My question is, if I use cudaMallocHost(), can I get access to the pointers in struct residing in host memory.

Pardon me if this question sounds silly, I am pretty new to CUDA programming.

Edit : I am working on face recognition and I want to pass images to the device memory. These are some of the structs I am using

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int rows, cols;
    int *data;
}  IMAGE;

typedef struct 
{ 
    int n; 
    IMAGE **list; 
} IMAGELIST;
```

I was trying to do this, which was obviously wrong.

```
IMAGELIST *d_ptr; 
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_ptr, sizeof(IMAGELIST));
```

Would a approach like this give me access to "list" in struct IMAGELIST?

```
IMAGELIST *d_ptr; 
cudaMallocHost((void **)&d_ptr, sizeof(IMAGELIST));
```

Comment: If you're using CUDA 6 you can use *unified virtual memory* with `cudaMallocManaged` and the runtime will take care of copying the pointees. Otherwise, yes, you have to copy the pointees yourself to the GPU (and fix the pointers).

Comment: You don't have to copy anything to the GPU, but you would have to use `cudaMallocHost` on each embedded pointer (allocation).

Comment: Thanks for replying. The version I have access to is, 4.2.9

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Could you elaborate a bit. I am working on face recognition and I want to pass images to the device memory. This is one of the struct I am using

typedef struct {
  int n;
  IMAGE **list;
} IMAGELIST;

I was trying to do this, which was obviously wrong.
      IMAGELIST *d_ptr;
      cudaMallocHost((void **)&d_ptr, sizeof(IMAGELIST));
      cudaMalloc((void **) &d_ptr, sizeof(IMAGELIST));

Would a approach lie this give me access to "list" in struct IMAGELIST?

    IMAGELIST *d_ptr;
    cudaMallocHost((void **)&d_ptr, sizeof(IMAGELIST));

Comment: Please edit that code into your question.

Comment: You can edit your own question.  Don't dump all this unformatted stuff into comments.  I don't have access to a CUDA 4.2.9 system to validate anything.  And if you intend to use `cudaMallocHost` for bulk, large-scale data access on the GPU, you're going to be very disappointed with performance.  The problem you're facing is the classic deep-copy problem.  It has been covered many times, in many questions on the CUDA tag.  You might search on "cuda 2D array" in the upper right hand corner to get some ideas.  The best suggestion is to flatten your data.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will go through them.

Comment: No, what you've posted won't work.  And you haven't provided enough details (e.g. the definition of `IMAGE`) for anyone to meaningfully help you, or provide a high-quality answer, except with equally vague suggestions.  Since you're new to SO, I suggest studying how to write a good question.  Starting out with something very vague, and then having long discussions to clarify things and dribble out additional bits of information, is not very productive.  Please study [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are likely not very familiar with the some of the rather important concepts like host/device memory space, addressing, page-locked memory, etc., so you may be better off with picking up some  understanding the basics (the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/) is a decent starting point).

What you seem to want to do is to build a struct that has pointer fields on the host and transfer it to the GPU. While you can pass the struct straight to the kernel, the memory the pointers point to will obviously not be copied. This is the problem referred to as [deep-copying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy) which in this case, with current CUDA, can be done either manually or automatically by the CUDA runtime when relying on the [unified memory features introduced in CUDA 6.0](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/) (see in particular the "Eliminate Deep Copies" example) . Now, you need to be aware that unless the copied data is large enough and there is enough computation to hide latencies, relying on the automated copies can result in very poor performance.

Although you say you want to use those data structures you showed, I would like to encourage you to consider "flattening" the data structures and instead of the commonly used pointer-heavy data structures like dynamically allocated struct fields and linked lists, whenever possible and reasonable, consider using fixed-sized arrays (e.g. `char name[MAX_NAME_LEN]`) or at least contiguous storage in arrays (you can use buffered allocation, it can help avoiding frequent reallocation in some cases). These can make the host-device data-shuffling code considerably simpler.

You asked about accessing memory allocated with `cudaMallocHost()` on the host. The answer is yes, but I strongly encourage you to read carefully [what page-locked memory is and how is it used](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think what you have suggested is the best option I have as of now. I tried flattening the data pointed by double pointers and eventually my code is running embarrassingly slower than the sequential version.

Comment: Which data transfer did you implement, explicit memcopies? I suggest you run it through the visual profiler in guided mode, it can hint you which part of the code is limiting performance.